# Content Area within Fixed Positioned Panel Won't Scroll

Tags: css, layout, scroll, css-position

***Foreward:*** After getting no response from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330162/chrome-screwing-up-fixed-positioning-on-sticky-elements) question and having no better thoughts on how to hack it to work, I decided just to try my layout again from scratch. But the link and this note are really only for your reference, they don't necessarily affect this question.

I'm building a web page where if the user scrolls past the page header, the page will become a "full-screen" page, with two fixed-positioned toolbars, one at the top of the screen and another at the bottom. The bottom bar is "attached" to an offscreen content area (that is, they are both wrapped in a container `div`). Then, when the bottom bar is clicked, the secondary content panel will slide up below the top toolbar and fill the remaining on-screen space, down to the bottom of the viewport.

Most of this is working just fine, but I have one last problem. If the content in that secondary content area exceeds the height of the screen, it will get "clipped" (but perhaps not in the CSS sense) and a scrollbar will *not* appear, even if the container div is given the style `overflow: auto`. (If `overflow: scroll` is used instead, the scrollbar shows up, of course, but scrolling is still not possible). Is there a problem with my markup somewhere which is preventing scrolling (either an HTML issue, more likely a CSS issue, or maybe some wild combination)?

As a test case, I added the jQuery UI "resizeable" widget to my content area and then *was* able to successfully get a working scrollbar. The only thing it did was add the class "ui-resizable" to the content container, with the style `position: relative`, but just adding that to the standard `.container.comment` did not achieve the same effect. Of course, I do not actually want this content area to be resizable, but it proved the concept is at least, in theory, possible.

**The Goods:**

URL in question: http://weathersourcepa.com/iProj/newsticky/stickies2.html

Class Hierarchy for bottom ("comment" panel):

```
.commentarea          <-- Section container
.commentbar           <-- Toolbar
.container.comments   <-- Container for the content area
   .content.comments  <-- The actual content area for this part of the page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but think you're over-complicating this. Based on your layout, you could probably get away with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMH7U/6/)

For the HTML we use a simple HTML5 markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="top-content">The content at the top</div>
    <div id="main">
        <header>Toolbar #1</header>
        <div id="posts">
            <p>Lots of repeated content</p>
        </div>
        <footer>Toolbar #2</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then we use a standard div to house the `#top-content`, and fixed positions for the `header` and `footer`. To make sure the main content area, `#posts` isn't getting cut-off, we give it top and bottom margins.

To make sure the fixed `header` doesn't overlap `#top-content` we apply some basic JavaScript to set its offset depending on the window's top offset.

```
$(window).scroll(setToolbarOffset);

function setToolbarOffset(){
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    var headerOffset = (top > 50) ? 0 : 50 - top;
    $("header").css("top", headerOffset);
}

setToolbarOffset();
```

If fixed heights are an issue, you can easily determine the heights and adjust the CSS accordingly with jQuery/whatever.

Feel free to chime in if you think I'm missing your point.

Comment: This is a very clean, nice solution if I only needed one content area between two toolbars, however the problem is I do need a second content area to fly up when the second toolbar is clicked (see the page, the rough functionality should be there). I built it with that particular class system in mind partially as a "stub" for the potential of adding a "draggable" property to that second content area somewhere down the road.

That said, I appreciate your efforts and could still be possibly over-complicating things somewhere (I'm good at doing that! :])

Comment: @Devin Just for kicks I updated the jsFiddle for you (http://jsfiddle.net/pMH7U/7/) - Both content areas could easily interact, and you could also add a dynamic margin based on if the toolbar is toggled. Sky's the limit, I'm sure you'll figure it out. Too many possibilities to make what you want happen, if you have a specific issue in the future, re-ask the question and I'm sure you'll get a response.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really good! I've been making some progress on my own since posting this, so I'll have to see if it's possible to meet in the middle somewhere (though that can wait for Monday at this time of the day!)